# C++ - defenition - private inheritance

Tags: c++, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Private/protected inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374399/private-protected-inheritance)

Can you give me example for private inheritance in `C++`? As I understood, in this sort of inheritance, the public and the protected features of the parent don't filter throght the child, and only the public features of the child are visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Private Inheritance***:
All `Public` members of the Base Class become `Private` Members of the Derived class &
All `Protected` members of the Base Class become `Private` Members of the Derived Class.

An code Example:

```
Class Base
{
    public:
      int a;
    protected:
      int b;
    private:
      int c;
};

class Derived:private Base   //Not mentioning private is OK because for classes it  defaults to private 
{
    void doSomething()
    {
        a = 10;  //Allowed 
        b = 20;  //Allowed
        c = 30;  //Not Allowed, Compiler Error
    }
};

class Derived2:public Derived
{
    void doSomethingMore()
    {
        a = 10;  //Not Allowed, Compiler Error, a is private member of Derived now
        b = 20;  //Not Allowed, Compiler Error, b is private member of Derived now
        c = 30;  //Not Allowed, Compiler Error
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived obj;
    obj.a = 10;  //Not Allowed, Compiler Error
    obj.b = 20;  //Not Allowed, Compiler Error
    obj.c = 30;  //Not Allowed, Compiler Error

}
```

If you are inclined to know about Inheritance & Access specifiers you can check out more at **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447498/cannot-access-private-member-of-a-class-error-in-c/5448004#5448004)** answer I posted quite a while ago.

Answer (score 0):

Private inheritance is usually used as a form of composition. It is not much different from having a member variable of the inherited type.

It means "**implemented in terms of ...**"

In some rare edge cases, it may be more efficient than having a member variable.

The most common usage of private inheritance I'm aware of is [boost::noncopyable](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/utility/utility.htm)