# classifying a heritage

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have an exam coming up in the near future and I'm really stuck on a question that I couldn't find any answers on.

Suppose that a class `CI` inherits class `Sup` as:

```
class CI: protected Sup
{};
```

Why is this not a classifying heritage?

Thanks in advance and I appreciate all help.

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/prot-vs-priv-inherit.html

Comment: First time I see the word "classifying inheritance"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, only public inheritance is deemed as real inheritance, which means a subclass will inherit the **interface** of its superclass(i.e IS-A relationship). A decent inheritance should satisfy [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

As for protected/private inheritance, they're actually kind of containment/composition, for a derived class will hide its base class's interface(as protected/private member) and only make use of base class's **implementation**(i.e. HAS-A or Is-Implemented-In-Terms-Of relationship).

You may refer to this question on SO for better understanding: [Why do we actually need Private or Protected inheritance in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374399/why-do-we-actually-need-private-or-protected-inheritance-in-c)

That said, protected/private inheritance is an arguable feature in C++, which is abandoned by C++ successors like Java and C#.