# Enabling/Disabling feature specific flags for compiling

Tags: c++, makefile

This is in regard to the post
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4171484/1220659

I want to know where and how to enable the flag UNIT_TEST. I guess, it has something to do with makefile. But I am completely a newbie in this.

Comment: What do you use to compile/build your code? Maybe g++ and Make, or Visual Studio, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got what I am looking for, I just have to add -D option with the flag in the makefile.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.google.com/search?q=add+%23define+to+makefile

If you're using Visual Studio:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx