# Why is a "friend class" not verified for existence?

Tags: c++, friend

I used to name my test class as a friend in the class to be tested, in order to enable testing private fields. I noticed that the name of the class is not verified for existence. Is it by intention?

Comment: *"I used to name my test class as a friend in the class to be tested in order to enable testing private fields."* - That's a horrible idea. Testing must not break encapsulation.

Comment: Declarations *create* names. They don't check for existence of names.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you have and what part of it you think should not work?

Comment: @ChristianHackl related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171310/what-is-wrong-with-making-a-unit-test-a-friend-of-the-class-it-is-testing

Comment: @ChristianHackl: There is black box testing, and then there is white box testing.  White box testing does break encapsulation.

Comment: @ChristianHackl black-box testing: fly the aircraft and see if it crashes. White-box testing: take the aircraft apart, check critical components for hairline cracks, then put the aircraft back together. Aircraft undergo white-box testing regularly.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou: Then `friend` unit tests are like letting the testers fly in the aircraft every time alongside the passengers? There's only so much value in comparing computer programs with real-life things, you know...

Comment: @ Christian Hackl  I am in the process of implementation, and after implementing some new detail, I test it, rather than stepping and debugging. Not making tests for a ready-made project. I do not find it horrible, but I wonder what your offered/preferred method is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A friend class declaration that uses an elaborated type specifier with *non-qualified* name of the class is actually a *declaration* of that class. It *introduces* the class as a member of the enclosing namespace. It does not require it to be pre-declared

```
class C
{
  friend class X; // OK, introduces '::X'
};
```

But if you use a *qualified* name in a friend class declaration, it will be subjected to a regular qualified name lookup. And it must refer to a previously declared name

```
class X {};

class C
{
  friend ::X; // OK, refers to '::X'
  friend ::Y; // Error, no '::Y' in sight
};
```

So, if you want your class name to be "verified for existence", use qualified names in friend declarations.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it by intention?

I think so. It's much like a forward declaration.

Usually the `friend` class needs a full declaration of the friended class, but not vice versa.

---

To force checking an existent (declared) type you can use

```
class MyClass {
    friend FriendClass;
};
```

as mentioned in [@bogdan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42008500/why-a-friend-class-is-not-verifyed-for-existence/42008557?noredirect=1#comment71193001_42008557).

---

<sub>As a side note:

How to refactor the mostly not appropriate friend pattern, I recommend you to read my Q&A post: [**How can I remove refactor a «friend» dependency declaration properly?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492132/how-can-i-remove-refactor-a-friend-dependency-declaration-properly)</sub>

Comment: You can say `friend X;` instead of `friend class X;` and then it will require a previous declaration. Maybe this will help the OP.

Comment: @bogdan Interesting. I wasn't aware of that syntax subtlety.

Comment: If i'm reading the standard right (**[dcl.type.elab]**) it's because the declaring work is done by `class` and `friend` is just a modifier. There are a couple caveats a little later in **[class.friend]** note 11 about scope that I'm working through in my head.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine if the friend class was required to exist. How would you structure your code? For testing you have that friend declaration in your code. When you build your shipping version you aren't going to ship the test code, so you have to remove the friend declarations and rebuild everything. Now you're shipping code that's different from the code that you tested.

Comment: See reply from bogdan and AnT. Otherwise I am not sticking to a friend. During the development phase, something debug/release solution would also do. Like asserting.