# C++ use of "friend"

Tags: c++, inheritance, friend

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should you use 'friend' in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434/when-should-you-use-friend-in-c)

So I know a class or function can be keyworded as friend but what does that mean and how do I use it? I've tried reading around but no one explains what the following means:

```
class x{
public:
friend function(int x);
};
```

Why do i declare function a friend, what use does that give me. Also, what does it mean to declare a class a friend? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A friend function is basically declared in a class, but defined outside of it. It is given special access to class's otherwise restricted (ie: private) internal members.

See: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/

Comment: Does it HAVE to be defined outside? That's where I went to try to understand friend but it was no help. What is the use of a friend function?

Comment: @Richard: Did you read that article? The top chunk of it describes it pretty clearly. If you wouldn't want to define it outside of it, then it'd just be a method of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what the `private` and `protected` keywords mean?

`friend` functions, and all member functions of `friend` classes, bypass the accessibility checks.