# Friend function - practical use?

Tags: c++, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should you use 'friend' in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434/when-should-you-use-friend-in-c)

[There is a detailed explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434/when-should-you-use-friend-in-c), but I would like to know what is the practical use of Friend function.

How I can decide when I should go with a friend function rather than a member function?

Comment: If you don't know, then you don't need `friend`.

Comment: There are practical examples in a question you linked.

Comment: Yes there are some practical examples like it can be used to test, but how far it is usable in client-side ??

Comment: It's usable just as far as anything else is. I don't understand what you're asking. The other question covers cases where it might be useful. But again, the important general principle is that you don't need it unless you need it. You'll know when that time comes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases, `friend` declarations are a code-smell <strike>since it breaks encapsulation</strike>.

Developers often use `friend` for a quick-fix to a problem. However a good starting design or some refactoring (more often more than less) exclude the necessity for it.

EDIT:

Even in @Darhuuk's example, a friend declaration is not needed. You can have getters for the specific fields you want to print.

Comment: It is theoretically possible for it to enhance encapsulation. For example, assuming that the fields you wanted to print were not fields that you wanted to expose publically. Although I very much agree with the general principle that `friend` can often be avoided by better design.

Comment: Friend functions don't break encapsulation any more than public member functions do. Both have the same level of access, and both must be declared in the class definition.

Comment: @CodyGray I **personally** find overriding `operator <<` a little "code-smellish". I'd personally prefer a "toString()" or "print()" method. But I agree `<<` is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

You would use a friend when the function needs to be a non-member, but also needs access to class members.

Common examples where you need a non-member function are:

- An API that requires non-member functions; for example, `boost::intrusive_ptr` requires that you implement `intrusive_add_ref()` and `intrusive_release()` as non-member functions.
- Overloading a binary operator where your type need to be the right-hand operand; for example `operator<<(ostream&, my_type const &)`.
- Overloading a binary operator where you want the left-hand side to be convertible to your type; for example, if your class is constructible from `int`, then `5 + my_type` will work if you define a non-member `operator+(my_type const&, my_type const&);`, but not if you define a member `my_type::operator+(my_type const &) const;`.

Whether any of these needs to be friends depends on whether they can do their job using the class's public interface; for example, you could add a public `print(ostream&)` member that `operator<<` could use, and a public `operator+=` member that `operator+` could use.

As an example of implementing `operator+` in terms of `operator+=`:

```
my_type & my_type::operator+=(my_type const & rhs)
{
    // do addition here
    return *this;
}

// The first operand is passed by value, giving a modifiable copy
my_type operator+(my_type lhs, my_type const & rhs)
{
    return lhs += rhs;
}
```

Comment: +1, best answer so far I think. The last paragraph is especially helpful as it gives some practical advice how to avoid `friend` by using a better design. The `operator+=` part is a bit unclear to me, though. Doesn't it also need to access private members of the operand in most cases where `operator+` would?

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark: Assignment operators (including `+=`) can only be overloaded as members; so they have access anyway. I'll add an example of implementing `operator+` in terms of that.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, only the standard version of assignment needs to be a (non-static) member function; all compound assignment operators can be non-member functions.  If so, then they may need to be `friend`s with their operand(s)' class(es).

Comment: Implementing `op` in terms of `op=` necessarily disqualifies the former from being `constexpr`.  If you're making a `constexpr`-enabled type, then you need to flip the dependencies between the two operators and probably make the former a `friend` (maybe defined in-class).

Comment: I feel adding a `print` member function solely to avoid making `operator <<` a `friend` is a code smell, due to repeating yourself.  The operator is the standard method of getting a lexical serialization of a type.  (It's the same category as making all member data practically public through `get`/`set` member functions to avoid other friendships.)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest use case would probably be when overloading the stream output operator for a custom class.

For example, take a look at the following code (shamelessly copied from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Cpp/0200__Operator-Overloading/friendostreamoperatorforprivatefields.htm)). In this case the use of `friend` allows the non-class method to access the private fields of class, thus preventing the need to code several `get` methods (which otherwise you might not even want to create).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
class MyClass {
  // now private
  char name[80];
  int areacode;
  int prefix;
  int num;
public:
  MyClass(char *n, int a, int p, int nm)
  {
    strcpy(name, n);
    areacode = a;
    prefix = p;
    num = nm;
  }
  friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, MyClass o);
};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, MyClass o)
{
  stream << o.name << " ";
  stream << "(" << o.areacode << ") ";
  stream << o.prefix << "-" << o.num << "\n";

  return stream;
}

int main() {
  MyClass a("T", 1, 5, 1);
  MyClass b("A", 3, 5, 5);
  MyClass c("T", 2, 5, 9);

  cout << a << b << c;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think in this example if you allow to print the value of members, you should also provide getters for them, thus making the use of `friend` superfluous.

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark :) Funny you should say that, I had just edited my answer with the same argument.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: It seems like this argument is kind of obvious ;)

Comment: @Niklas Baumstark, I think good OOP design assumes that your object has _methods_ to preform actions, but not a lot of _getters_ and _setters_ that _actually_ break encapsulation, while _serializtion_ method `operator <<` actually _hides_ realization details, but _perform action_.

Comment: @Lol4t0: If the private members in the example really are implementation details, why should they be printed out then?

Comment: @Niklas Baumstark, Serialized, not printed. And then deserialized by the same class.

Comment: @Lol4t0: It can also be used to output the object to `std::cout`, for example. Also, I don't see the deserialization routine, so I don't think the example makes that use case clear. A better example would be `operator+`, I think, as it often needs to know the other operands internal representation of data to perform the addition.

Comment: @Niklas Baumstark, `bost::serializtion` is done through `operator <<`, if I not mistaken. I agree, that `operator+` could be more obvious example.