# Why Private CRTP Base Class has to be declared friend?

Tags: c++, inheritance, crtp

https://stackoverflow.com/a/365349/5455629

Here the user says

```
// we derive privately, so the base-class wouldn't notice that, 
// (even though it's the base itself!), so we need a friend declaration
// to make the base a friend of us.
```

Is there any documentation available for the same. I could find it. Thanks.

PS :  I can't add comment to that answer, as I am new here, and don't have sufficient reputation.

Comment: You don't need the `friend` declaration. You can use a C cast in the base class and it will work without it: `((Derived*)this)->getSomething()`. This is due to special wording in expr.cast/4.