# How to make thread access a private members of a class

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, private-members

I am new to c++ programming.
I have created a thread and a object of a class in it.
This class is in another project. 
Now how to access the private members of this class in the thread because i want to set them.Their is no methods for setting this members.
Can we anyone help me please.
Thanks.

Comment: "Project" is a bunch of source files; a "thread" is a run-time entity. It's not quite clear what you're trying to access and failing. Also, a concrete example (with some code) would be useful. Finally, only the implementation of class methods can access the class' private members - unless you use the [`friend`ing mechanism](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend).

Answer (score 1):

Well, your question is somewhat vague, but if you want non-class-member code to be able to access private class member, you can add the function which needs to access the code as a [friend](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) of the class. This is **highly unrecommended** except in [specific circumstances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434/when-should-you-use-friend-in-c) - since it breaks the encapsulation of your class and creates more complicated and delicate dependencies - and you should avoid doing so without a good reason.

Most likely, you need to reconsider *why* that member is private - and how that squares with your supposed need to access it from outside the class. Perhaps it just needs, say, a "getter" method which is guaranteed not to change the object (a `const` method)? Perhaps you can use another, public, method of the class instead of accessing the private member directly? Think about it.