# How to fix breaking strong encapsulation rules with CRTP implementation?

Tags: c++, encapsulation, crtp

I like [NVI idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-virtual_interface_pattern).

But sometimes I want to reduce vftable cost from NVI idiom.
Then I tried to apply [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to NVI as following.

```
template<typename E>
class unary_interface {
public:
    virtual ~unary_interface() = default;

public:
    double operator()(const double x) const
    {
        return static_cast<const E&>(*this).apply(x);   //occurs compile error!!!
    }
};

class square : public unary_interface<square> {
private:
    double apply(const double x) const
    {
        return x * x;
    }
};
```

But this code occurs compile error.

If I change apply function in private field to public, encapsulation is broken.
I got an idea that opaque alias solve this problem as following.

```
template<typename E>
class unary_interface {
public:
    virtual ~unary_interface() = default;

protected:
    class input_type {
    public:
        explicit input_type(const double x) : _x(x) {}
        operator double() const
        {
            return _x;
        }
    private:
        const double _x;
    };

public:
    double operator()(const double x) const
    {
        return static_cast<const E&>(*this).apply(input_type(x));
    }
};

class square : public unary_interface<square> {
    using base_type = unary_interface<square>;
public:
    double apply(const base_type::input_type& d) const
    {
        const double x = static_cast<const double>(d);
        return x * x;
    }
};
```

This design keeps to disable to access apply function except from operator() of unary_interface.

At first glance "apply function" is exposed to user code, but apply function is accept only protected opaque alias type that is defined on unary_interface in protected field.
I think that this combination is very good and reduce virtual function cost with keeping strong encapsulation.

Does this idea has any defect that I can not find out, and do you have a specific name for this design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But this code occurs compile error.
>   ...
>   At first glance "apply function" is exposed to user code, but apply function is accept only protected opaque alias type that is defined on unary_interface in protected field. I think that this combination is very good and reduce virtual function cost with keeping strong encapsulation.

You can easily solve your *strong encapsulation* dilemma using `friend` (and in that case it won't come with any [negative consequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434/when-should-you-use-friend-in-c)):

```
class square : public unary_interface<square> {
    friend class unary_interface<square>; // <<<
    double apply(const double x) const // <<< Keep apply() private
    {
        return x * x;
    }
};
```

No need to deviate using the `protected input_type`.

See [**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/acedec5474e0f385) please.

> Does this idea has any defect that I can not find out, and do you have a specific name for this design?

Well, the defect is *over-complicating* the situation and presenting the final user a public function they cannot actually use.

I don't know if that *anti-pattern* already was identified and named. That somehow misuses the `public` interface area by declaring promises that cannot effectively be used at the public API.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I agree that complicated design is bad. At first, I got idea of using friend. I wrongly thought that friend is always deprecated, but I see that friend is efficient tool in the specific situation thanks to you.

Comment: @YusukeMori Glad to be helpful. You may need to find a better title for that question. But in general it's considerable and useful. There's a different case when you expose `private` internal class _handles_, that can be used with `auto` from the `public` ´API.