# Why won't this code, implementing PassKey pattern, compile?

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns, friend-class

Here is the code, c++11 :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>

template<typename T>
class Passkey
{
    friend T;
    Passkey() {}
    Passkey(const Passkey&) {}
    Passkey& operator=(const Passkey&) = delete;
};

class Access;

class MyClass
{
   public:
      MyClass() {}

   private:
      void func(Passkey<Access>) { std::cout<<"here" << std::endl;}
};

class Access
{
    public:
      void tryme(MyClass& c) { c.func(Passkey<Access>());} 
};

int main ()
{
   MyClass c;
   Access a;
   a.tryme(c);
   return 0;
}
```

Compiler is giving the following errors:

```
prog.cpp: In member function 'void Access::tryme(MyClass&)':

prog.cpp:21:12: error: 'void MyClass::func(Passkey<Access>)' is private
           void func(Passkey<Access>) { std::cout<<"here" << std::endl;}
                ^

prog.cpp:27:56: error: within this context
     void tryme(MyClass& c) { c.func(Passkey<Access>());}
```

Comment: Corrected your line numbers, see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c0d57e905880ac9).

Comment: The compiler is telling you exactly why it's not compiling. Do you think it's wrong? If so, why? If not, why do you expect to access private members from outside the class (and without `friend`)?

Comment: I just wanted to post a comment to say thanks for bringing the "Passkey" pattern to my attention.  I had never heard of it before.  Interesting technique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pewt said, `MyClass::func()` must be `public` in order for `Access::tryme()` to be able to access it.  In the [example you linked in the comments](https://www.spiria.com/en/blog/desktop-software/passkey-idiom-and-better-friendship-c), `Citizen::getSocialSecurityNumber()` is actually `public`.  And that is fine, because the access is limited in a different way.

Your `MyClass::func()` takes a `Passkey<Access>` parameter – and **no one is actually allowed to construct such an object apart from the `Access` class itself**.  All of `Passkey`'s functions are `private`. By construction, `Access` is the only `friend` of `Passkey<Access>`, so only `Access` can construct the “key” required to call `func()`.  So `func()` behaves as if it were private, without actually being private itself.

Comment: Ahh yes that's it.I completely overlooked that and assume the function would be private,but obviously makes sense..thank you!

Comment: Glad we could help. If you find that your question has been answered, remember to [choose the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem, and mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

`func()` is a `private` method for `MyClass`. `Access` can't call `func` unless it is made a `friend` of `MyClass`.

Making `PassKey` a `friend` of `Access` does not (as far as I know...) allow use of `MyClass`'s `private` methods.

Via https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_classes#Member_functions

> The private members are not accessible outside the class; they can be accessed only through methods of the class.

And [When should you use 'friend' in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434/when-should-you-use-friend-in-c)

Comment: The whole point of the Passkey pattern is to avoid using `friend` like that. But the OP is doing Passkey wrong.

Comment: I've implemented it according to: https://www.spiria.com/en/blog/desktop-software/passkey-idiom-and-better-friendship-c .  I suppose it's incorrect.

Comment: Ah thanks. Not familiar with the pattern: I was just commenting on why the code wasn't building.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  Every article I've read about passkey implements it using friend this way.   Where have you seen different?

Comment: The linked article implements it differently then how you are using it above.

Comment: @pewt  yes as mindriot pointed out the function I'm trying to restrict access to must be public obviously..  thanks!

Comment: @SubliminalBroccoli Usually it compiles ;)