# Do friend functions violate encapsulation?

Tags: c++, oop, encapsulation, friend, access-modifiers

Use of `friend` function seems like a little hack to me. Do `friend` functions violate the concept of encapsulation?

What are the alternatives to `friend` function? Will using a simple helper class/function along with *setter* & *getter* member functions help increase encapsulation in comparison with just using `friend`?

Comment: Well, a simple class with only a getter and a setter is... no different than having these member public. You're only lying to yourself. A friend function is actually more helpful to encapsulate, since you target directly who can access your members.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot:    But will sharing of such `secret keys` with others create confusion in the code ( esply big projects) later - const-ness of member functions etc

Comment: [When should you use 'friend' in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17434/62576) (found with a quick search) might help.

Comment: Scott Meyers has written a number of articles about member functions, non-member friends, and non-member non-friends  - and how they can affect encapsulation.  You'll be able to find a fair number with google.  Some of the details of his thinking have changed over time. Bear in mind that encapsulation is not really a desirable property in its own right - it is one way of controlling and localising effects of change and therefore contributes to properties like flexibility (ability to control change) and robustness (not introducing unintended flaws when making change).

Comment: This question is not opinion-based if you measure the degree of encapsulation as the amount of code which the compiler allows access to another piece of code.

Answer (score 4):

> Do `friend` functions violate the concept of encapsulation?

In fact, **it doesn't**. First of, notice it doesn't violate encapsulation more than `public` members do. Are `public` members a violation of the concept of encapsulation? Obviously not. More so, in many situations `friend` increases encapsulation rather then violates it, as it allows you to maintain the `private` stuff as `private`, instead of having to expose data system-wide using `public` members, which makes the entire concept of it being `private` hidden from the naked eye. This is the opposite of delivering intent in your code, and should raise a red flag when noticed. `friend` allows you to mitigate this issue, as it gives you control over exactly who can access these members that are being kept `private` for everyone to know they are. [The C++ FAQ raises one example](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/friends#friends-and-encap) in which you can use `friend` to solve a design issue such that you exercise this control over the access to a point where you haven't increased *at all* the amount of code that has access to the `private` parts.

> Shouldn't a simple helper class/function along with setter & getter member functions can rescue this design flaw ?

Well, using a helper class could definitely answer some of the same needs that `friend` do, but many times are unjustifiably more cumbersome than just using `friend`. About function or getter/setter, that just sounds to me like using *public* members to directly expose *private* ones, the disadvantages of which are described above.

> ... or shouldn't it be treated as a poor design practice ?

As an end note, try avoiding subjective questions in here, like whether something should or shouldn't be treated as X. Let's stick to facts! : )

Answer (score 1):

> Does friend function violates concept of encapsulation

No, it **enhances** encapsulation because the alternative would be to make the member `public`.