# Getters and Setters vs FRIEND_TEST

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I know this is not good class design for UT but...

In case there are protected variables that need to be tested, would it be better to just use FRIEND_TEST to get/set these variables on test?  Or should I create getters and setters (for each variable!)?

Ex.

```
class Dog
{
public:
//some methods

protected:
   int age;
   std::string color;
   std::string breed
}
```

Declaring a FRIEND_TEST will not require much overhead unlike if I will create getters and setters for each == 6 new methods!  But what is the more correct solution?

Comment: It feels like you want to test some internals of your class that ain't observable from the outside. I would question if this is a good idea. In the end, you are allowed to change implementation as long as you don't violate your external promised behavior. (If you don't want to update all callers). It would be strange that such change would break your test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need only one class be able to access your protected members, use friends classes. This is an absolute rule in C++.

Adding getters and setters to your class will just add overhead and, in the best case, your compiler will remove it.

If you want more information about friend classes [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434/when-should-you-use-friend-in-c) link will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

1. FREIND_TEST is not a good solution as you have no real control who gets access to the protected members.
2. You may define the tested class as an inner class of the tester class. enable this nesting only on test builds.

Comment: But isn't FRIEND_TEST specific per test case only?

Comment: an evil user can define a test class and use it to access your classes.

Comment: An evil user can still access private data, even without `friend`. :-/