# Can you overload the << operator in c++ without the friend tag

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Instead of doing:

```
friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& output, const classType& object);
```

Can you still overload the `operator<<` without using `friend`?

Comment: Yes, but what are you _really_ trying to do? Your question would benefit from a [mcve] and for explanation on why you don't want to use `friend`.

Comment: You can omit `friend` if the operator accesses public members only. If it needs to access protected/private members then `friend` is needed

Comment: I usually make a public member function `void print(std::ostream&) const`, and then have a non-friend `operator<<` which just called `obj.print(o); return o;` thunking, inline function.

Comment: @Eljay, you can improve on that by using `std::ostream& print(std::ostream&) const;` and then use `return obj.print(o);`.

Comment: You must also have tried `ostream& operator <<(ostream& output, const classType& object);`. What was the result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should you use 'friend' in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434/when-should-you-use-friend-in-c)