# How Can I Overload The == Operator to Compare Armadillo Vectors?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, armadillo, subclassing

In my program, I use many `arma::uvec`s, and check equality between them like this

```cpp
#include <armadillo>
using Vec = typename arma::uvec;
Vec v1({0, 0});
Vec v2({0, 1});
bool are_equal = arma::all(v1 == v2);
```

as I couldn't find any better equality operator [in the Armadillo docs](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#part_classes). Now that works perfectly fine, but to save some space, and as an exercise in subclassing and operator overloading, I want to define the equality sign *directly* between the vectors like this:

```cpp
class Vec : public arma::uvec {
    friend bool operator==(const Collapsed& lhs, const Collapsed& rhs) {
        return arma::all(lhs == rhs);
    }
};
```

But sadly, I can't get it to work like that. I'm grateful about any hints!

Comment: Your implemetation would work fine I think if you don't put it in a subclass, but as a global function instead. It looks to me like you misunderstand what `friend` does.

Comment: Thanks! Truth is: I don't understand what `friend` does *at all*. It didn't work without it, and then I got the hint to prepend `friend` by a friend (no pun intended).

Comment: Ah ok, well `friend` is not used to implement functions. I put some links in my answer

Answer (score 2):

Operator overloads do not need to be part of a class. I would suggest implementing your comparison operator as a free function like this:

```
bool operator==(const arma::uvec& lhs, const arma::uvec& rhs) {
    return arma::all(lhs == rhs);
}
```

Regarding the `friend` in your question: As a quick summary, it provides the function that is befriended access to private and protected members of the class where the friend declaration is located. It it is not used to implement functions.
You can read more about it on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) or on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17434/10362622)

**EDIT**
Since the above only works if `operator==` is not already defined, here is a version that overrides it's implementation for a custom subclass:

```
class Vec : public arma::uvec
{
public:
    bool operator==(const Vec& other)
    {
        // depending on wether arma implemets operator== as member or free function
        // return arma::all(this->arma::uvec::operator==(other));
        return arma::all(arma::operator==(*this, other));
    }

};
```

Comment: Actually, it throws an `error: no matching function for call to 'all'`, as I assess it because we use the very `==` operator between the two objects we're defining it for, inside its own definition. Is there some other operator we could use, or can we redefine it w/o using it?

Comment: `lhs == rhs` inside an `operator==` is clearly a recursion. Some casting is needed to force use of different overload of operator.

Comment: Ah yes I didn't think about that. In that case we can define the operator for your own `Vec` class. That needs to be a subclass now instead of an alias.

Comment: Actually, we need to inherit the constructor, too. So far I couldn't figure how to adapt that from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347358/inheriting-constructors)

Comment: does putting `using uvec::uvec;` not work for inheriting the constructor?

Comment: Yes, `using arma::uvec::uvec;` works, but both your uses of `arma::all` throw me an `error: no member named 'operator==' in 'arma::Col<unsigned long long>'` and an `error: no matching function for call to 'operator=='` for the first resp. second option you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is library itself:

[Armadillo: C++ library for linear algebra & scientific computing](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#operators)

> **operators:  `+  −  *  %  /  ==  !=  <=  >=  <  >  &&  ||`**
>
> - Overloaded operators for *Mat*, *Col*, *Row* and *Cube* classes
> - Operations:
>   `+`  addition of two objects
>
>   `−` subtraction of one object from another or negation of an object
>
>   `*` matrix multiplication of two objects; not applicable to the *Cube* class unless multiplying by a scalar
>
>   `%` element-wise multiplication of two objects (Schur product)
>
>   `/` element-wise division of an object by another object or a scalar
>
>   `==` element-wise equality evaluation of two objects; **generates a matrix/cube of type *umat*/*ucube***
>
>   `!=` element-wise non-equality evaluation of two objects; generates a matrix/cube of type *umat*/*ucube*

and `uvec` is:

> uvec = `ucolvec = Col<uword>`

so `operator==` is already there and its functionality is strange/unexpected.

My recommendation is: do not fight with a library. Do not try provide own operator. Just provide a named function `areEqual`.

Defining a class just to provide own equal operator is not a best choice and if doing that then IMO it is better to use composition not inheritance (depending on requirement it will be  more boiler plate code in class itself, but it will be easier to avoid unexpected behaviors).